# ASP.Net MVC 5 Dynamic add field to form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to dynamically add fields to a form by clicking a button. I can add fields by calling ajax but the data won't post back to server side. I understand the reason that adding fields only adds content to client side but not server side, but how am I supposed to do this using ASP.Net MVC 5?

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SKU { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public List<Price> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to add more price fields to the product form by clicking a button.

Comment: check this article out. https://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2014/08/how-to-dynamically-via-ajax-add-new-items-to-a-bound-list-model-in-asp-mvc-net/

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you create a model and manipulate it in the client side according to your needs, once the user submit the form. Pass this model to the action and you will have all your data there, in the server side.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now. I created a fixed number list of price fields. I was trying to create a expandable list, like a shopping cart, where you can add as many products as you want, but not a fixed number.